# Get only business days in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I wish to get only business days between the two dates. I know we have many solutions on my question but I am looking for something particularly for my example

my sql query has a condition

```
WHERE DATE_FIELD BETWEEN '1-JAN-13' AND '31-MAR-13'
AND (DATE_FIELD1 - DATE_FIELD2) > 10
```

I wish to get only business days between the two dates and also I want that during the calculation of DATE_FIELD1 - DATE_FIELD2, it only considers business days and excludes weekends.

Comment: well holydays are your problem. You have to parametrize a table where you store the holidays in your region, and then make a function for that..

Comment: You need to define your holdays in a calendar table. Oracle doesn't know when Australia day or thanksgiving or defender of the fatherland day occurs, or what the particular set holidays you observe are. You can identify weekeds easily enough though.

Comment: I have removed the condition for holidays. I just need to get business days and also get the calculated field (DATE_FIELD1 - DATE_FIELD2) > 10 for just business days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counting of working days is possible with [truncation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions230.htm#i1002084) to start date of the week.

Determine start of the week and subtract it from date value to get a number of the week day:

```
date_field2-trunc(date_field2,'D')
```

After that it's possible to count number of working days between to dates:

```
select 
  nvl(sum(
    case

    when 
        (
          (date_field1 + (level-1))
          -
          trunc(date_field1 + (level-1),'D')
         ) 
           > 4 then 0

      else 1
    end
  ),0)
from 
  dual 
start with 
  date_field2 > date_field1
connect by 
  level < (date_field2 - date_field1)
```

and incorporate this value into a query:

```
with sample_table as (
  select 
    trunc(sysdate)             date_field1,
    trunc(sysdate) + level - 1 date_field2
  from dual 
  connect by level <= 20
)
select 
  to_char(date_field1, 'yyyy-mm-dd') date_field1,
  to_char(date_field2, 'yyyy-mm-dd') date_field2,
  date_field2-trunc(date_field2,'D') date_field2_week_day,
  (date_field2 - date_field1)        days_between,
  (
    select 
      nvl(sum(
        case

        when 
            (
              (date_field1 + (level-1))
              -
              trunc(date_field1 + (level-1),'D')
             ) 
               > 4 then 0

          else 1
        end
      ),0)
    from dual 
    start with date_field2 > date_field1
    connect by 
      level < (date_field2 - date_field1) 
  )                                  
                                     work_days_between 

from 
  sample_table
where 
  (
    select 
      nvl(sum(
        case

        when 
            (
              (date_field1 + (level-1))
              -
              trunc(date_field1 + (level-1),'D')
             ) 
               > 4 then 0

          else 1
        end
      ),0)
    from dual 
    start with date_field2 > date_field1
    connect by 
      level < (date_field2 - date_field1) 
  )                                  
    > 10
```

or make a function to return corresponding number of days:

```
create or replace function get_work_days_between(
  pDate1 in date,
  pDate2 in date
) return number deterministic parallel_enable 
as
  vResult number;
  vDate1  date;
  vDate2  date;
begin

  vDate1 := trunc(pDate1);
  vDate2 := trunc(pDate2);

  select 
    nvl(sum(
      case

      when 
      (
        (vDate1 + (level-1))
        -
        trunc(vDate1 + (level-1),'D')
      ) 
      > 4 then 0

      else 1
      end
    ),0)
  into 
    vResult
  from 
    dual 
  start with 
    vDate2 > vDate1
  connect by 
    level < (vDate2 - vDate1) 
  ;

  return vResult;

end;
```

and use it in query:

```
with sample_table as (
  select 
    trunc(sysdate)             date_field1,
    trunc(sysdate) + level - 1 date_field2
  from dual 
  connect by level <= 20
)
select 
  to_char(date_field1, 'yyyy-mm-dd')              date_field1,
  to_char(date_field2, 'yyyy-mm-dd')              date_field2,
  date_field2-trunc(date_field2,'D')              date_field2_week_day,
  (date_field2 - date_field1)                     days_between,
  get_work_days_between(date_field1, date_field2) work_days_between
from 
  sample_table
where 
  get_work_days_between(date_field1, date_field2) > 10
;
```

[**<kbd>SQLFiddle examples</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a4f92/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH dates AS
(
        SELECT          (TO_DATE('01-JAN-13', 'DD-MON-YY') - 1) + LEVEL       AS d_date
        ,       TO_CHAR((TO_DATE('01-JAN-13', 'DD-MON-YY') - 1) + LEVEL, 'D') AS d_day_no
        FROM    DUAL
        CONNECT BY
                LEVEL < ABS(TO_DATE('01-JAN-13', 'DD-MON-YY') - TO_DATE('31-MAR-13', 'DD-MON-YY')) + 2
)
SELECT  *
FROM    A_TABLE
WHERE   DATE_FIELD IN    -- Instead of: WHERE DATE_FIELD BETWEEN '1-JAN-13' AND '31-MAR-13'
        (
            SELECT  d_date
            FROM    dates
            WHERE   d_day_no NOT IN (6, 7)    -- Skip: Sat and Sun
        )
AND     (DATE_FIELD1 - DATE_FIELD2) > 10
;
```